# Adding and removing event listeners in Javascript for a responsive menu

Tags: javascript, menu, dom-events, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

0

I wrote a function that reveals/hides a menu when the user click on a menu icon. I want it to hide the menu when the user clicks anywhere outside the menu, and open again if the user clicks in the icon.

So far, the menu is closed/hidden by default, so when i click the menu icon, the menu opens and when I click the icon while the menu is open, then it closes. I want to menu to close by clicking the menu icon or anywhere on the screen.

Can I add event listener in the else statement to close the menu when the user clicks on the screen? And how can I remove the event listener after the user clicked on it the first time?

```js
function smallMenu() {
    var x = document.getElementById("buttons");
    if (x.className === "optionBar") {
        // opens the menu
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        // closes the menu
        x.className = "optionBar";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="optionBar" id="buttons">
            <div id="containerSelector" class="align">
                <!-- options for screen display -->
                <div id="elementSelector" class="displayOptions"style="border: 3px solid green;">
                    <!-- group by system -->
                    <button onclick="">
                        <span class="butIcon">
                            <i class="fas fa-columns"></i>
                        </span>Group by System
                    </button>

                    <!-- hide graphs-->
                    <button onclick="toggleGraphsFunction()">
                        <span class="butIcon">
                            <i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i>
                        </span><span id="butName">Hide Graphs</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <!--refresh and elipsis container-->
                <div class="displayOptions2"style="border: 3px solid red;">
                    <!-- refresh icon -->
                    <a href="#" class="refresh">
                        <i class="fa fa-redo"></i>
                    </a>
                    <!-- elipsis menu for small screens-->
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="menuSmall()">
                        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide some basic HTML?

Comment: You should use the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) methods to check, add or remove classnames.

Comment: @theblackgigant what's the difference between using classList and className?

Comment: @zfrisch I added some html, I'm not sure if that's enough to help

Comment: @user12324017 It makes sure you dont accidentally remove classnames you need. And it also helps for readability purposes, `classList.add("something")` tells me that it is adding a classname but with `className += "something"` it takes a second to realize what it does.

Comment: @theblackgigant aaahh thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

And another thing, you have not added the id "buttons" to the menu.

```js
document.getElementById("bodyId").addEventListener("click", function(){
document.getElementById("buttons").classList.add("hideButton");
});
```

```css
.hideButton{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body id=bodyId>
<!--Rest of the code goes here-->
</body>
```

Comment: If I use this method, how can can I ensure that the menu closes when I click on the icon again?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding a click handler to the element that wraps the page - i've worked up a demo on [codepen](https://codepen.io/mcgraw/collab/KKVVRdK) - added animated gif of demo in case codepen isn't cooperating

```
    (function () {
  const els = {
    page: document.querySelector("#page"),
    sidebar: document.querySelector("#sidebar"),
    content: document.querySelector("#content"),
    wrapper4: document.querySelector("#wrapper4")
  };
  const handleSidebarClick = (el) => {
    console.log("sidebar click");
    el.style.background = getRandomColor();
    els.wrapper4.innerText = "Wootwoot, You Clicked the Sidebar!";
  };

  const handleClickOutside = (id) => {
    console.log("outside sidebar click", id);
    els.sidebar.style.background = "rgba(251, 131, 0, 0.2)";
    els.wrapper4.innerText = "Hey Now, You Clicked the " + id + " !";
  };

  const getRandomColor = () => {
    var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    var color = "#";
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
  };

  els.page.addEventListener(
    "click",
    (e) => {
      if (e.target.id === 'sidebar') {
        handleSidebarClick(e.target);
      } else if (e.target.id !== 'sidebar') {
        handleClickOutside(e.target.id);
      }
      // e.target.id === "sidebar" ? handleSidebarClick(e.target) : handleClickOutside(e.target.id);
    }
  );

  els.page.removeEventListener("click", handleSidebarClick);
})();
```

[image]